# Is there a Oracle issues database?

Tags: oracle

Does anyone knows where to find the description for an Oracle issue? That is the oracle issue database?

I have found a patch for my product, and the release notes says ( in my own words )

```
Fixed that important problem eveyone's having: ( Issue #844073 )
```

But I don't know where that issue may be to know if THAT problem is MY problem too.

**EDIT**

I have reviewed into metalink, but I don't find where to enter this number.

Comment: are you using oracle express?

Comment: @djangofan. No, albpm6.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle Metalink.   https://metalink.oracle.com/

You'll need an account to use it.

Comment: Metalink aaaannd then?

Comment: Just enter the number in the search box in the upper right hand corner.  This doesn't return any results, so that number does not appear to be a published Oracle bug.  If you're talking about Oracle the company rather than Oracle the database and the product you're talking about is something Oracle acquired recently, it's possible that you'd need to go to metalink3.oracle.com-- I haven't kept up on which products still use that portal.

Comment: Thank you Justin. I have contacted oracle support and they said that ticket was not public in metalink

Answer (score 0):

If it's an issue with Oracle, you choose the new "my oracle" interface, you can type the issue into the "search knowledge" box and it will show you the issue as one of your search results.

Answer (score -1):

The product seems to be AquaLogic BPM 6.0.4, right?

Oracle doesn't use the terminology "Issue number", it uses "Bug number" in its products. To look up a bug, login a metalink, enter the number in search field, choose "Bug Number" from the drop down and search. You'll see the bug if it is publicly published. However, bug 844073 is for an unrelated Oracle product(JDeveloper). I think your issue number is from a pre-Oracle BEA product. I don't know how these are handled. So, again, I would suggest opening an SR in metalink so support could help you.

Another option isto  ask in Oracle forums in otn.oracle.com, which might help as well:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=560&start=0

just my two cents...

Comment: The question is pretty clear: "where to find the description for an Oracle issue?" and added context: The read me files say etc. etc.  The bug description IS unprofessional indeed ( did you read I said IN MY OWN WORDS )  though the REAL is pretty much the same:  "Datamart and BAM services are handling incorrectly some exceptions. (Issue # 8440738)" but I didn't mean to add specific details for I didn't want to distract from the real question: Where is ( if it exists ) the oracle issued database ( like sun's bug database ) It may probably exist but I didn't knew.

Comment: >".. or do yo just randomly install patches" No, that's exactly my point I wanted to know what that patched solved in first place. I've got the patch from metalink of course. I asked in oracle forums but the answer were useless ( well a little bit more useful than .. nevermind )

Comment: Sorry if you perceived it unhelpful, let me try again. Oracle doesn't use the terminology "Issue number", it uses "Bug number" in its products. To look up a bug, login a metalink, enter the number in search field, choose "Bug Number" from the drop down and search. You'll see the bug if it is puclicly published. However, bug 844073 is for an unrelated Oracle product(JDeveloper). I think your issue number is from a pre-Oracle BEA product. I don't know how these are handled. So, again, I would suggest opening an SR in metalink so support could help you, or use the relevant forum in Oracle website

Comment: Now, that's useful :) Could you please add this comment to your answer so I can upvote you ;-)